# Show text dynamical from a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for something which shows the text from a textarea below it without clicking any submit buttons. (Like Stackoverflow's preview below). I have the HTML code but am new to JavaScript so if anyone could help be out with this, I'll be grateful.

Like the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pure Javascript:

```
 <input onkeyup="document.getElementById('demo').innerText='you typed ' + this.value">
 <div id="demo"></div>
```

You should seperate your markup and your script and use handlers.
This can also be done with pure (vanilla) javascript but it is easier with the jQuery library: http://www.jquery.com

demo.js

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#mytext").keyup(function(){
     $("#demo").text("You typed: " + this.value);
  });
});
```

demo.html

```
<html>
  <head>   
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="mytext"><div id="demo"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: WTF! Maybe in some cases the jQuery way is easier, but here not at all. Why did you recommend jQuery? http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3305/addanumbertoanothernumb.png

Comment: @Mageek your profile already tells that you don't like jQuery. That's fine but I guess any answer to your question would lead to an endless discussion. As you can see both solutions are shown.